# Netsuite Add Order PHP Toolkit

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm trying to add a sales order into netsuite using their PHP Toolkit however It is throwing an error.

Custom price level id is 1 ADD ERROR

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm using their sample file they included.

```
<?php

require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

$service = new NetSuiteService();

$svr = new getSelectValueRequest();
$svr->fieldDescription = new GetSelectValueFieldDescription();
$svr->pageIndex = 1;
/*$svr->fieldDescription->recordType = RecordType::salesOrder;
$svr->fieldDescription->sublist = "itemList";
$svr->fieldDescription->field = "price";
$svr->fieldDescription->
*/

$priceFields = array(
    'recordType'  => RecordType::salesOrder,
    'sublist'    => 'itemList',
    'field'    => 'price',
    'filterByValueList'    => array(
        'filterBy'    => array(
            array(
            'field'    => 'item',
            'sublist'    => 'itemList',
            'internalId'        => '458',
        )
            )
    )
);

setFields($svr->fieldDescription, $priceFields);

$gsv = $service->getSelectValue($svr);

$id = null;
foreach($gsv->getSelectValueResult->baseRefList->baseRef as $pricelevel) {
    if ($pricelevel->name == 'Base Price') {
        $id = $pricelevel->internalId;
        break;
    }
}


if ($id != null) {
    echo "Custom price level id is " . $id . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Custom price level not found " . $id . "\n";
}

$so = new SalesOrder();
$so->entity = new RecordRef();
$so->entity->internalId = 21;
$so->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$soi = new SalesOrderItem();
$soi->item = new RecordRef();
$soi->item->internalId = 104;
$soi->quantity = 3;
$soi->price = new RecordRef();
$soi->price->internalId = $id;
$soi->amount = 55.3;
$so->itemList->item = array($soi);

$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record = $so;

$addResponse = $service->add($request);

if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "ADD ERROR";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Holy smokes!

Price Levels - if you're looking for the ID of Base Price, it's going to be 1. Always. Don't need any looping or lookups - it's just 1. You can modify the name of a Price Level, even Base Price, so your code will fail if someone renames it.

The Sales Order itself - I generally like to create the RecordRefs separately, then assign them to the sales order fields.

```
$entityRR = new RecordRef();
$entityRR->internalId = 21;
$entityRR->recordType = "customer";

$so->entity = $entityRR;
```

...

for the item list, you should be able to do something like this (off the top of my head and untested, but gives you the general idea):

```
$item = new SalesOrderItem();

$itemRR = new RecordRef();
$itemRR->internalId = 104;
$itemRR->recordType = "inventoryItem";

$pricelevelRR = new RecordRef();
$pricelevelRR->internalId = -1;
$pricelevelRR->recordType = "priceLevel";

$item->item = $itemRR;
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->price = $pricelevelRR;
$item->rate = 55.3;

$so->itemList = array($item);
```

NOTE: the Amount field is read only. It's the quantity * rate, and is populated on a Read request. Also, if you're providing the Rate value and not using one of the price levels, you set the price level to "Custom", which is -1.

The rest of your code to actually add the order looks OK to me.

Comment: thanks for the info. is there any sort of documentation for their php api? I still can't seem to add a sales order correctly.

Comment: Do you have the zip file that contains the php Tootlkit? There are some samples in there, including adding a Sales Order. I will take a look at it and update my answer if I find issues with what I wrote.

Please post the XML sent to and returned from NetSuite.

Comment: I see - your code comes from the example in the Toolkit. You really need to post the XML for me to help more.